# Is this a proper subset?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A \cap C = \{1\}$ and $C = \{1,5\}$. Is it true that:

$A \cap C = C$?

For this to be true I know that they $A \cap C$ must be a subset of $C$ and $C$ must be a subset of $A \cap C$.

So I found that $A \cap C$ is a subset of $C$ since $1$ belongs to $C$. But I wasn't sure if $C$ was a subset of $A \cap C$ since the former containes $5$?

Comment: C is not a subset of AnC, as 5 is in the former, but not the latter.

Answer (score 1):

$5\in C$ but $5\notin A\cap C$, so $C\not\subseteq A\cap C$ and $A\cap C\neq C$. However, $A\cap C\subseteq C$. Therefore, $A\cap C\subsetneq C$.

Comment: Thanks, how would this be expressed as subsets/proper subsets?